# Join in hibernate with annotaion

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, join

I am trying to perform join in hibernate and i am using struts2.
I am working with hibernate using annotaions. Now i am unable to perform join between two tables.My first table is "studentprojects" which contain pid and email.Second table is "initialprojectdetials" which contains pid,name,description... similarly some other fields.I have to get the data of second table by performing join around pid of first table.
For this am using this query:

```
String hql="from InitialProjectDTO I join I.projectId S where I.projectId=:id";
        Query query=session.createQuery(hql);
        query.setParameter("id", id);
        mail =query.list();
```

where mail is the arraylist of InitialProjectDTO.
And my InitialProjectDTO is:

```
package edu.pma.dto;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;



@Entity
@Table(name="initialprojectdetail")
public class InitialProjectDTO {

    @Id
    @Column(name="projectId")
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="studentprojects",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="projectId"))
    int projectId;

    @Column(name="name")
    String name;

    @Column(name="description")
    String description;

    @Column(name="technology")
    String technology;

    @Column(name="guide")
    String guide;

    @Column(name="duration")
    int duration;

    @Column(name="status")
    String status;
    @Column(name="report")
    String report;

    public String getReport() {
        return report;
    }

    public void setReport(String report) {
        this.report = report;
    }

    public int getProjectId() {
        return projectId;
    }

    public void setProjectId(int projectId) {
        this.projectId = projectId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getTechnology() {
        return technology;
    }

    public void setTechnology(String technology) {
        this.technology = technology;
    }

    public String getGuide() {
        return guide;
    }

    public void setGuide(String guide) {
        this.guide = guide;
    }

    public int getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(int duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

}
```

my SudentProjectDTO is:

```
package edu.pma.dto;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="studentprojects")
public class StudentProjectDTO {

    public int getProjectId() {
        return projectId;
    }
    public void setProjectId(int projectId) {
        this.projectId = projectId;
    }
    @Id
    @Column(name="email")
    String email;
    @Column(name="projectId")
    int projectId;
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

This is the error which i am getting:

```
Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements: edu.pma.dto.InitialProjectDTO.projectId
Method "execute" failed for object edu.pma.actions.LoginAction@1096a56
File:   org/hibernate/cfg/annotations/CollectionBinder.java
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But it didn't works for me. I using annotation therefore i can't add any extra field in my DTO class except those which are the part  db table. Therefore its giving me the error of not building the sesdion factory .

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use different models

```
@Entity
public class InitialProjectDTO {

 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project")
 private Collection<StudentProjectDTO> students;

}

@Entity
public class StudentProjectDTO {

 @ManyToOne
 private InitialProjectDTO project;

}
```

And with the proper model it shuld be easy to write hql, you might want to look here for examples https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html.

Also I would suggest to look here for example of models. http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-one-to-many-annotation-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

See following example might its help to you

```
@Entity
@Table(name="initialprojectdetail")
public class InitialProjectDTO {


    private Integer initialProjectDTOId;
    private Set<StudentProjectDTO > studentProjectDTO  = new HashSet<StudentProjectDTO >(0);

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "initial_projectDTO_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getInitialProjectDTOId() {
        return this.initialProjectDTOId;
    }

    public void setInitialProjectDTOId(Integer initialProjectDTOId) {
        this.initialProjectDTOId = initialProjectDTOId;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "studentprojects", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    public Set<StudentProjectDTO> getUserRole() {
        return this.studentProjectDTO;
    }

    public void setUserRole(Set<StudentProjectDTO> studentProjectDTO) {
        this.studentProjectDTO = studentProjectDTO;
    }  

}

@Entity
@Table(name="studentprojects")
public class StudentProjectDTO {

    private InitialProjectDTO project;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "initial_projectDTO_id", nullable = false)
    public User getProject() {
        return this.project;
    }

    public void setProject(InitialProjectDTO project) {
        this.project = project;
    }
}
```

your Query shoud be something like this

```
String hql="SELECT ip from InitialProjectDTO ip JOIN ip.studentProjectDTO sp WHERE sp.projectId = :id";
        Query query=session.createQuery(hql);
        query.setParameter("id", id);
        mail =query.list();
```